# Execution of initstate for every instance

Tags: android, dart, flutter

in my app I have a navigation drawer and the body is updated according to the tile pressed in the drawer. The body is the same for each class, it is a statefulwidget and returns a listview. For each instance of this class (and so for every tile) I need to call the initState method. I notice that it is called just on the first instance of the first tile, then it call just the build method. How can I run a piece of code the first time for every instance?

Synthesis: in the app there's a drawer with many tile, each tile is associated with an instance of a class that is the body of the app. But the initState is called just on th first instance.

Here's an example:

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPage createState() => new _FirstPage();
}

class _FirstPage extends State<FirstPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("debug");
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('hi');
    return ListView(children: <Widget>[Text('text')],
    );
  }
}
```

If I instantiate this class the first time it prints: debug and hi. The second time I instantiate this it prints just: hi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The whole point of `initState` is to be called once on state initialization.

You may want to look at other life cycles. Such as

- [didUpdateWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html)
- [didChangeDependencies](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html)